# How can I use multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, multipartform-data

I need to implement a REST-Endpoint, that receives multipart/form-data
I use 
- Spring Boot 
- Kotlin
- Spring MVC

A multipart form submit with the following parts:

deployment-name ----- text/plain 
enable-duplicate-filtering ----- text/plain 
deploy-changed-only ----- text/plain 
deployment-source ----- text/plain 
tenant-id ----- text/plain 
* ----- application/octet-stream

The Rest Controller looks so:

```
    @PostMapping("/data/deployment/create")
    fun uploadDmn(@RequestBody() file: Any){

    }
```

When I receive a request, then there is an error:

> Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------914124725006223485188585;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

If I use "MultipartFile" instead of any, then is file NULL.

```
    @PostMapping("/data/deployment/create")
    fun uploadDmn(@RequestBody() file: MultipartFile){

    }
```

Example of Request:

```
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deployment-name"

aName
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enable-duplicate-filtering"

true
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deployment-source"

process application
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="test.bpmn"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions ...>
  <!-- BPMN 2.0 XML omitted -->
</bpmn2:definitions>
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9--
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit has documentation on [`FORM ENCODED AND MULTIPART`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

The gist is to annotate the function with `@Multipart` and annotate your file as `@Part`

Comment: That works without Retrofit if I use
`@RequestParam("deployment-name")
            deploymentName: String`

But for the last argument from type application/octet-stream that doesn't work.
With `@Multipart` and `@Part` too. "Parameter specified as non-null is null"